# Need of :: to specify class for functions but not variables?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, scope

Why do I need to use :: to denote if a function is a member function but I don't need to do it for the instance variables? I do understand that :: is used to differentiate between standalone and member functions, but I still don't get the variables part. I'll give an example of what I'm talking about.

### Shape.h

```
# pragma once

class Shape {

private:
  int height;
  int width;

public:
  Shape(int height, int width);
  int getHeight();
  int getWidth();
}
```

### Shape.cpp

```
#include "Shape.hpp"

Shape::Shape(int height, int width) {
  this->height = height;
  this->width = width;
}

int Shape::getHeight() {
  return height;
}

int Shape::getWidth() {
  return width;
}
```

Here, I have to to specify the class of the `Shape` constructor and the getters in order for the compiler to know what I'm talking about. So how come when I do `return height;` or `this->height` without specifying class it understands what I'm talking about.

Comment: It’s not “needed to refer to functions”. It’s needed for a non-inline method definition. The “Shape::” would not be needed in this case if the methods were defined in the class declaration (where the variables are defined..).

Comment: The implicit this (why “this->” is not required to refer to members) is a separate concern. Questions on SO work best if they remain focused.

Comment: Anyway, it’s all just syntax. In C++ the “Shape::” is required in such cases so the compiler knows what class the methods are being defined for - a single .cpp file can contain definitions for methods in multiple classes. Other languages rely entirely on “class {..}” scoping (etc.) to determine associations.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for the explanation. I can kind of visualize it now.

Comment: You need `::` equally for defining (static) member variables; those are just rarer.

Comment: `this->` is only "needed" because you named the class members the same as the function parameters (and chose not to use the ctor-initializer list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ uses a model where it initially assumes everything is in the same namespace/class as what it's declared in unless stated otherwise. So, for example, if you write

```
int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
```

at the top level of a C++ file, the compiler assumes you're declaring something in the global namespace. That means that `getHeight` is a free function. Then, the statement `return height;` is interpreted in the context of a free function in the global namespace - it'll start searching local variables for `height`, then global variables in the global namespace.

On the other hand, if you write

```
int Shape::getHeight() {
    return height;
}
```

you're explicitly telling C++ "hey, I know that this code is in the global namespace at the top level, but I'm explicitly indicating that this is actually inside of the `Shape` class." At that point, the compiler says "ah, gotcha, you're inside `Shape` now" and interprets the code that's written as though it were inside `Shape`. In that sense, the statement `return height;` first starts looking for a local variable named `height`, then looks for a data member of `Shape` named `height`, then looks for global variables named `height`.

There's no fundamental reason why C++ had to do things this way, but there is a nice internal consistency to it. You stay at whatever "scope level" a statement or definition appears unless something explicitly moves you into a different scope level. So once you've declared the function in a way that says it's in `Shape`, everything inside it evaluates relative to `Shape` rather than to the global namespace.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that this is also consistent with needing `Shape::` to access static objects in a class.

Answer (score 1):

*but not variable*. this is not true, you have to use `::` if you want to get value outside the scope of the `A` class.

```
class A { 
    public:
        const static int a = 5;
        A (){}
};

int main (void) {
    std::cout << A::a;
}
```

Comment: "...from outside the scope of the `A` class."